# How to use the old visio as default instead of the new visio

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-visio

I have 2 version of Visio on my PC, Visio 2010 and Visio 2016.

The only reason I install Visio 2016 is to be able to read/edit/(some time create) the Drawing of newer Visio. But I want to use Visio 2010 as my default Visio, but now when I have installed Visio 2010, each time I open a Visio Drawing in Word, it open with Visio 2016 - not Visio 2010. Each time I open a Visio 2010 Drawing, it open with Visio 2016 - I can fix this by open Visio 2010 and browse to the Drawing, but if a Drawing inside a Word document, I can't do this.

At least is there a way to open a Visio Drawing inside Word with Visio 2010 instead of Visio 2016.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change file associations by right clicking on a file, selecting "Open with> chose default program", and in the following dialogue look through the items or browse to the old version of Visio. Check the option "Always use the selected program".

Alternatively, type "default" into the start menu, and open "Default programs". Work through the options there.

Comment: Silly me :) Thank you for reminding me
Here is the path to the Visio 2010 in case manually browse for the app: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\VISIO.EXE

Comment: Wait a minute, even when I set default programs for Visio 2010, the on the next day, when open a Visio Drawing inside Word, it still opens with Visio 2016, I have to open Visio 2010 - go through some configuration - Just like Jon Fournier's answer https://superuser.com/a/1205623/525666 . I personally think we have to combine this answer and Jon Fournier's answer to archive this.

Answer (score 1):

I have two versions of Visio on my PC.  For me the file association goes to whatever version of Visio I started last.  So to change the default on my Windows 7 PC, I just go through the start menu and start whatever version of Visio I want.  It usually seems to go through some configuration step but then the next time I start Visio it'll be that same version again.